# Set axis offset dynamically on seaborn.despine()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I wanted to calculate the axis offset for seaborn.despine() dynamically. It should stick to the 0 value of my matplotlib axes. But somehow it seems I have the wrong concept of calculating it.

As I need to set seaborn's offset in points I tried to calculate the image size, and set it into proportion with the x-axis with, but as it can be seen in the small code sample below this doen't work as desired.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)

# Create sample data
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))

# Plot
sns.set(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

pal = sns.color_palette("hls")
# Initialize the FacetGrid object
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=20, height=0.7, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=0.7, lw=2, bw='scott')
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="k", lw=1, bw='scott')

g.map(label, "x")

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)


# calculate offset for left axis
ax = g.axes[0]
ax_size = abs(ax[0].get_xlim()[0]) + ax[0].get_xlim()[1]
fig = g.fig
size = fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi
fig_size = size[0]
off = fig_size * ax[0].get_xlim()[0] / ax_size

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=False, left=False, offset={'left':off}); # set offset
```

the plot looks like this:
[image: Plot]

as it can be seen, the axis is way off the zero-value. 
Anyone an idea how to get this right?

Thanks in advance,

Exi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice MWE. There are some [issues](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11227) [with](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/11232) how specifications in points are handled in matplotlib and I think the problem is potentially related to them. Try to avoid any specification in points for the time being.

Seaborn's 'despine' forces the use of points; however, we can fall back to the corresponding matplotlib function which is more flexible, and even has a convenient shorthand for centering the spines on the data origin.

```
for ax in g.axes.ravel():
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
```

[image]

Also, I recommend you read up on [transformations in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html), then you don't need to figure them out by hand as you did when computing `off`.